# Pandas - Delete cells based on ranking within column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete values based on their relative rank within their column. Specifically, I want to isolate the X highest and X lowest values within several columns. So if X=2 and my dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    Val1    Val2    Val3    
001   2       8       14      
002   10      15      8
003   3       1       20
004   11      11      7
005   14      4       19
```

The output should look like this:

```
ID    Val1    Val2    Val3    
001   2       NaN     NaN      
002   NaN     15      8
003   3       1       20
004   11      11      7
005   14      4       19
```

I know that I can make a sub-table to isolate the high and low rank using:

```
df = df.sort('Column Name')
df2 = df.head(X) # OR: df.tail(X)
```

And I figure I clear these sub-tables of the values from other columns using:

```
df2['Other Column'] = np.NaN
df2['Other Column B'] = np.NaN
```

Then merge the sub-tables back together in a way that replaces NaN values when there is data in one of the tables. I tried:

```
df2.update(df3) # df3 is a sub-table made the same way as df2 using a different column
```

Which only updated rows already present in df2.

I tried:

```
out = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='outer')
```

which gave me separate rows when a row appeared in both df2 and d3

I tried:

```
out = df2.combine_first(df3)
```

which over-wrote numerical values with found NaN values in some cases making it unsuitable.

There must be a way to do this: **I want to the original dataframe with NaN values plugged in whenever a value is not among the X highest or X lowest values in that column.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question, you can get the index of the values of each columns in the sorted values of each columns (here in the `mask` `DataFrame`), and then keep the values that have the index within you defined boundary.

```
In [98]:
print df
    Val1  Val2  Val3
ID                  
1      2     8    14
2     10    15     8
3      3     1    20
4     11    11     7
5     14     4    19
In [99]:

mask = df.apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(sorted(x),x))
print mask
    Val1  Val2  Val3
ID                  
1      0     2     2
2      2     4     1
3      1     0     4
4      3     3     0
5      4     1     3
In [100]:

print (mask<=1)|(mask>=(len(mask)-2))
     Val1   Val2   Val3
ID                     
1    True  False  False
2   False   True   True
3    True   True   True
4    True   True   True
5    True   True   True
In [101]:

print df.where((mask<=1)|(mask>=(len(mask)-2)))
    Val1  Val2  Val3
ID                  
1      2   NaN   NaN
2    NaN    15     8
3      3     1    20
4     11    11     7
5     14     4    19
```